# Jenkins - scriptler scripts require admin approval, how to auto-approve scripts?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, authorization, jenkins-scriptler, jcasc

I have scripts in Scriptler plugin that **require** **approval** from administrator.

I'm running Jenkins in K8S and I'm adding scripts into /var/jenkins_home/scriptler/scripts.

How do I **auto approve** new scripts or disable the request to approve?

Things I have done **that didn't work** -
I have installed 'permissive-script-security' plugin and enabled it.